Google Business Profile Performance - how can more people view my GBP than have searched for it
I have a new business and are working on building our Google Business Profile. I am looking at the performance. Towards the bottom of the overview tab I see these figures.

Can anyone explain what each of these sections actually relates to. In particular, I am confused as to how people can have viewed my business profile without having first searched for it, bearing in mind that we are new business and I don't believe people will be searching for the business directly.

All these metrics are what we call impressions. They are looking for a massage services and Google is suggesting your business. That doesn't mean they click and look for that specific service.
From this metrics, I will highly recommend to make your website mobile friendly. Most of searches are from mobile.
The one on the right are the most searches related on your local area and industry.
Make sure to have a website detailing each of your services, and what clients can expect if they work with you.
I hope this help!
